# Rails Migration: How to increase column data type size by using ROR migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

My users table login column is String type with limit of 40 characters.
Now I am planning to increase the limit to 55 characters.

Any one please let me know how can we increase this limit by using ROR migration.

Thanks,
Sravan

Answer (score 78):

```
class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :users, :login, :string, :limit => 55
  end

  def down
    change_column :users, :login, :string, :limit => 40
  end
end
```

Comment: will this destroy or preserve existing values in the production database?

Comment: In my experience, this will preserve data, and is considered a safe action.

Comment: I don't like this solution, or the one below, as they are possibly not reversible. When you have data that is longer than 40 characters for the login string and you try to rollback the migration you will get the following error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(40).

Answer (score 29):

```
class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :login, :string, :limit => 55
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem reversible without the previous limit in the migration

Comment: Yes, @ChrisBeck this migration is irreversible.

Comment: FYI a rollback on this raises ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration

Answer (score 0):

After you increase character limit, Suppose you insert some data longer than 40 characters.

Now you run `db:rollback`, and some existing data does not fit in 40 characters:

- there can show database error or,
- in existing data, the string will truncate and, you will lose some characters.

To avoid this issue, I increase the limit in `up` but, do not change anything in `down`.

```rb
class FixUsersLogin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :users, :login, :string, limit: 55
  end

  def down
    # do nothing in rollback
  end
end
```